# Wordpress Action "update_user_meta" reading and updating

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to create an action when a user meta value is updated, swap the values.
but nothing is happening, any ideay why ?

```
function my_checkout_update_user_meta( $user_id ) {
    if(pll_current_language() == 'he')
    { 
        $first_name_input = isset($_POST['billing_first_name']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_first_name']) : '';
        $billing_company_input = isset($_POST['billing_company']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_company']) : '';
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', $billing_company_input );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', $first_name_input );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'my_checkout_update_user_meta' );
```

Comment: Try `add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'my_checkout_update_user_meta', 10, 1 );`

Comment: I tried that, nothing.